# Swift: "Mapper is not a type", using custom mapping class for arrays in swift and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, types

I have an 2 objective C classes:

- Class 1 scanDatabase (Scans a database and puts that into a mutable array)
- Class 2 Mapper (Is a mapping class for the database scan "model")

In objective C this successfully scans the database and puts it into a mutable array. Using the mapping class I can access individual groups of elements (AlbumTitles) like so:

```
 for (Mapper *mapper in scanResult) {
    NSLog(@"%@", mapper.AlbumTitle);
 }
```

Everything is working as it should and I can return individual elements from my array i.e as above I am only returning album titles.

I then need to use that array in Swift. I call the objective C in my Swift class and again it runs fine and creates the array. This is done with:

```
let scanTable = ScanTable();
let scanMapper = Mapper();

scanTable.scanTableDo();
```

but when I try to retrieve a particular set of items like Album title as I did in the objective C for loop above I get the error "scanMapper is not a type" (scanMapper is my swift instance of the objective C mapper class:

I tried two different ways and both have the same error:

```
 for mapper: scanMapper in scanTable.scanResult {
        print("\(mapper.AlbumTitle)")
    }


for object in scanTable.scanResult as! [scanMapper] {
    print("\(mapper.AlbumTitle)")
}
```

Can I use an objective C class as a model/mapper and not sure whether I would need to recreate it in Swift.

I will include the mapper and scanTable .h and .m code just in case it is needed, plus the bridging header:

Mapper.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>

@interface Mapper : AWSDynamoDBObjectModel <AWSDynamoDBModeling>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *SongID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Artist;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *SongURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *UserRatings;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *AVGUserRating;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Category;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *PictureURL;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *SongDuration;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *SongTitle;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *AVGMusicianRating;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *AlbumTitle;

@end
```

Mapper.m

```
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>
#import "Mapper.h"

@implementation Mapper

+ (NSString *)dynamoDBTableName {
    return @"Songs";
}

+ (NSString *)hashKeyAttribute {
    return @"SongID";
}

@end
```

ScanTable.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AWSDynamoDB/AWSDynamoDB.h>

@interface ScanTable : NSObject

- (void) scanTableDo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *scanResult;

@end
```

ScanTable.m

```
#import "ScanTable.h"
#import "Mapper.h"

@implementation ScanTable

- (void) scanTableDo {

    AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper *dynamoDBObjectMapper = [AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper];
    AWSDynamoDBScanExpression *scanExpression = [AWSDynamoDBScanExpression new];
    scanExpression.limit = @10;


    [[dynamoDBObjectMapper scan:[Mapper class]
                     expression:scanExpression]
     continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
         if (task.error) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Error: [%@]", task.error);
         }
         if (task.exception) {
             NSLog(@"The request failed. Exception: [%@]", task.exception);
         }
         if (task.result) {
             AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput *paginatedOutput = task.result;
             NSMutableArray *scanResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:paginatedOutput.items];  //// ADDED /////

             for (Mapper *mapper in scanResult) {
                 NSLog(@"%@", mapper.AlbumTitle);
             } 
         }
         return nil;
     }];            
}

@end
```

//EDITED ADDED BRIDGING HEADER//

MySampleApp-Bridging-Header.h:

```
//
//  MySampleApp-Bridging-Header.h
//  MySampleApp

#import "ScanTable.h"
#import "Mapper.h"
#import "Hello World.h"
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just as the error explains, you're attempting to cast the items in your array to `scanMapper`, which is a variable holding an instance of `Mapper`, not the `Mapper` type itself. Assuming that `scanTable.scanResult` is an NSArray of Mappers, try this instead:

```
guard let scanResult = scanTable.scanResult as? [Mapper] else {

    print("scanResult was not an array of mappers!")
    return
}

for mapper: Mapper in scanResult {

    print("\(mapper.AlbumTitle)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Patrick. "Mapper" is written in Objective C, so not sure how I can reference it in way you mentioned? That sort of feeds into my question do I have to rewrite the mapping class in swift and have one for saving (Obj - C) and one for retrieval (Swift). I tried the way you said and I get the error "NSArray does not conform to protocol sequence type".

Comment: @NicholasMuir Have you created an Objective-C bridging header yet? Check out this guide if not: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/ I'll update the answer to work with NSArray.

Comment: Yep I have. I will edit my question with the bridging header. The objective C scanTableDo() function is being called by swift and is running correctly. I also have the Mapper class in the bridging header.

Comment: @NicholasMuir Updated. Let me know if my example doesn't work for you.

Comment: thanks for your help. I get expected else after guard condition.

Comment: @NicholasMuir Fixed.

Comment: No errors. But I get cast from NSMutableArray to unrelated type [Mapper] always fails. And nothing happens.

Comment: @NicholasMuir try `scanTable.scanResult.copy` to create an NSArray.